# Adding max elements from each row in 2D vector such that row element $A_i$ is less that $A_(i+1)$

Tags: c++, vector

So, I what I want is to collect maximum element from each row(in a 2D vector) and push it into a new vector. And if the new vector is sorted I want the sum of all vector elements.

I tried it but the code is showing error : 
"cannot convert 'std::vector to 'int' assignment"

also, is my code correct?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t,n,v1;
vector < vector<int> > vec;
vector<int> max;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
 cin>>n;
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
 {  vector<int> row;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
     int val;
      cin>>val;
      row.push_back(val);   
     }
     vec.push_back(row);
       }    

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        v1=*max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        max.push_back(v1);
    }
}

if(is_sorted(max.begin(),max.end()))
{
    cout<<accumulate(max.begin(), max.end(),0)<<endl;

}

else
cout<<"-1"<<endl;

}
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        v1=*max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        max.push_back(v1);
    }
}
```

You are trying to get the largest element from `vec`, which is a vector of vectors, and add it to `max`, which is a vector of `int`. Probably what you want is something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    v1=*max_element(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end());
    max.push_back(v1);
}
```

Or with C++11:

```
for (const vector<int> &row : vec)  // Or: for (const auto &row : vec)
{
    v1=*max_element(row.begin(), row.end());
    max.push_back(v1);
}
```

Also, you should `#include <numeric>` before using `std::accumulate`.